# Как писать программы с использованием RS-485? Какие для этого есть библиотеки?

Tags: c++

Ну я знаю что к примеру если у прибора есть выход rs485, то с помощью программы можно получить данные на компьютер. А самому можно писать программы под rs485? Какие библиотеки нужны на с++? Правильно я понимаю, что rs485 это стандарт, и на разных приборах он работает и опрашивается одинаково? Или нет?

Comment: rs485 - физический интерфейс. Протоколы могут быть разными - например, при соответствующей организации вы можете общаться через драйвер последовательного (serial) порта

Comment: Под DOS и Windows доступ к портам можно получить как к файлам с зарезервированными именами (COM1, COM2, ... ). Никаке специальные библиотеки не нужны.